# Given normal equations with nonnegative solution, is there always a subsystem with nonnegative solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Given a system of normal equations $A^TAx=A^Tb$ where $A^TA$ is $n\times n$,

what I call the $i$th subsystem is the linear system of size $n-1\times n-1$ where the $i$th column of $A$ has been removed.

> **My question is: suppose the initial solution of $A^TAx=A^Tb$ is componentwise nonnegative (that is, $x\geq 0$), is it always true that at least one
> of the subsystems has a componentwise nonnegative solution?**

Example:

Given the initial normal equations $\begin{pmatrix}9&4&2\\4&5&0\\2&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}$, with the componentwise nonnegative solution $x=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{4}{3}\end{pmatrix}$,

the 3 subsystems are:

- $\begin{pmatrix}9&4\\4&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7\\3\end{pmatrix}$, with the solution $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{23}{29}\\\frac{-1}{29}\end{pmatrix}$
- $\begin{pmatrix}9&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7\\2\end{pmatrix}$, with the solution $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{5}\\\frac{4}{5}\end{pmatrix}$
- $\begin{pmatrix}5&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\end{pmatrix}$, with the solution $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{5}\\2\end{pmatrix}$.

We can observe that among the three solutions, there is at least one which is componentwise nonnegative (actually two in this case).

**Is this property true for every system of normal equations with componentwise nonnegative solution?**

I implemented a code testing this property on random examples, and I was not able to find a counterexample.

(question crossposted to [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490546/given-normal-equations-with-nonnegative-solution-is-there-always-a-subsystem-wi))

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of crossposting, it is usually advised that if you are unsure which site is appropriate, first post on MSE and if you don't receive an answer in a week or so, post to MO.

Comment: What do you mean by a  non-negative solution? x is a vector, so there isn't a clear definition of its sign

Comment: @Carlyle It is nonnegative componentwise.